# сортировка индексным массивом с++

Tags: c++, сортировка, структуры

Задача была написать тривиальную структуру и отсортировать ее в процентном соотношении по кол-ву поступивших в вуз учеников методом сортировки индексов.
Я понимаю, что ошибка кроется в пользовательской функции сортировки по индексам (indexSort, я так полагаю). Но как бы я не пытался, безрезультатно.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
    char name[10];
    int vip;
    int vuz;
    float pr;
} school;

void IndexSort(school arr[], int n, int *B) //алгоритм сортировки через     массив индексов
{
    int i, j, t = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        B[i] = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[B[i]].pr < arr[B[j]].pr)
            {
                t = B[i];
                B[i] = B[j];
                B[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, t, n;
    school S;

    std::cout << "Input amount of schools: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    school* arr = new school[n];
    int* B = new int[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Input school name: ";
        std::cin >> arr[i].name;
        std::cout << "Input amount of graduate school:";
        std::cin >> arr[i].vip;
        std::cout << "Input amount of already students:";
        std::cin >> arr[i].vuz;
        if (arr[i].vip < arr[i].vuz)
        {
            std::cout << "You did mistake, try again " << std::endl;
            break;
        }
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arr[i].pr = ((float)arr[i].vip / 100 * (float)arr[i].vuz);
}

IndexSort(arr, n, B);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::cout << arr[B[i]].name << "  " << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[B[i]].pr << "  " << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если считать, что ваша индексная сортировка пузырьком работает, то её результатом должен быть массив индексов `B[]`, отсортированный так, что на нулевом месте в нём стоит индекс записи с наименьшим `pr` и так далее.

Однако при выводе массив `B[]` вовсе не используется. Вероятно, вывод должен выглядеть так:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  {
    int k = B[i];
    cout << arr[k].name << "  " << arr[k].vip << "  " << arr[k].vuz << "  ";
}

или без введения новой переменной
arr[B[i]].name и т.п.
```

Здесь используется один и тот же неинициализированный экземпляр S, присваиваемый всем элементам массива:

```
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        S.pr = ((float)S.vip/(float)S.vuz)*100;
        arr[i] = S;
    }
```

Привёл код к рабочему состоянию:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

typedef struct
{
    char name[10];
    int vip;
    int vuz;
    float pr;
} school;

void IndexSort(school arr[], int n, int *B)
{
    int i, j, t = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        B[i] = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[B[i]].pr < arr[B[j]].pr)
            {
                t = B[i];
                B[i] = B[j];
                B[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, t, n;
    school S;

    std::cout << "Input amount of schools: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    school* arr = new school[n];
    int* B = new int[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Input school name: ";
        std::cin >> arr[i].name;
        std::cout << "Input amount of graduate school:";
        std::cin >> arr[i].vip;
        std::cout << "Input amount of already students:";
        std::cin >> arr[i].vuz;
        if (arr[i].vip < arr[i].vuz)
        {
            std::cout << "You did mistake, try again " << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i].pr = ((float)arr[i].vip / (float)arr[i].vuz) * 100;
    }

    IndexSort(arr, n, B);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << arr[B[i]].name << "  " << arr[B[i]].vip << "  " << arr[B[i]].pr << "  ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, действительно ошибся. Не заметил как записан вывод. Но при выводе массива (без введения новой переменной) опять возникает ошибка следующего характера.
`error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘school*’ and ‘school’)
   cout << arr[B[i]].name << "  " << arr[B[i]].vip << "  " << arr[B[i]].vuz << "  ";`

Comment: Где-то у Вас с типами напутано. А код этот в VS не скомпилируется, так что легко проверить не получится. Кроме того, что Ant заметил, я ещё косяк увидел, и, наверное, не последний. Дебажьте поэтапно.

Comment: беда, вроде более менее разобрался, но сортировка через индексный массив не срабатывает. Вам скинуть полный кусок кода?

Comment: немного подкорректировал, исправил свои ошибки. А вам чашечку чая за мой счет) Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

1. Сортировка массива индексов должна осуществлять доступ к исходному массиву именно и только через массив индексов

   ```
    ...
    if (arr[B[i]].pr < arr[B[j]].pr)
    {
      t=B[i];
      B[i]=B[j];
      B[j]=t;
    }
    ...
   ```
2. Непонятно, почему память под основные данные выделена через `new []`, а память под массив индексов якобы "выделена напрямую": `int B[n];`. К тому же `n` в этот момент у вас вообще не инициализировано. Что вы хотели сказать этим `int B[n];`, если в `n` содержится "мусор"?

   В любом случае, если `n` не является константой, то либо `new []`, либо `std::vector`. Никакого `int B[n];` в С++ не допускается.
3. Как уже правильно заметил @MBo, зачем вы сортировали свой массив индексов, если потом вы его вообще не используете?